# Making a toast directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

I'm building an application in Angular 1.5 and I'm doing all the CSS etc myself.
Until now, I've been handling errors and success messages by including the following code in all my html templates

```html
<div 
     class="toast" 
     ng-repeat="toast in vm.toasts"
     ng-class="{'success': toast.type == 1, 'error': toast.type == 2}">
  <p ng-bind="toast.msg"></p>
</div>
```

and then I've just been using vm.toasts.push(error) when handling errors / success messages.

What I'm looking to do is create a service which can handle the toasts.

I would like to always make my toasts direct children of id="wrapper", and it should be something as simple as calling toast.new(type, message);

Maybe this is very simple to achieve, but I haven't really grasped how to make custom directives and services yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad - You can take a look at the source code of an existing [toast](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) [directives](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) to learn better and get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a toast-service, and a toast-directive which listens to the service. Whenever I send an error-message to the toast-service, it is rendered in the directive.